# Java LDAP Authentication

Tags: java, ldap, openldap

I am trying to use LDAP for authentication. I am using the OpenLDAP library by Novell to do this (http://www.openldap.org/jldap/).

My issue is that it wants a full Distinguished Name to authenticate. However, what if I dont have the users OU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You search!

You need some identifying piece of information.  Username, email, full name.  Then you search for a user who uid= or mail= or whatever works.

That returns the full DN then you proceed from there.